# Itop data collector for OCS Inventory NG issue

Tags: windows, inventory, ocs

I have installed data collector for OCS Inventory NG into the Itop server of my company and I did all the instructions from the ItopHub documentation (https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=extensions:ocsng-data-collector-v2). However, when I run exec.php via command line, i get the following errors:

"Error: This user is not authorized to use the web services. (The profile REST Services User is required to access the REST web services)"
error msg: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Can somebody help me ? I don't know what I'm supposes to do to solve these errors

Answer (score 0):

**First symptom:** Error: This user is not authorized to use the web services. (The profile REST Services User is required to access the REST web services)

Regarding this symptom, it is because the iTop user you are using in the collector to connect to iTop doesn't have the "REST Services User" profile.

Connect to your iTop, edit the said user and add it the "REST Services User" profile.

**Second symptom:** error msg: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Regarding this symptom, it is most likely because you are using a self-signed certificate. Refer to [this documentation page](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=extensions:itop-data-collector-base#configuration) to see how to configure your collector to not verify the certificate:

> The following options might help if you're connecting using HTTPS:
> <curl_options>
> <CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST>0</CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST>
> <CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER>1</CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER>
> </curl_options>